# Soft credits created via API/hook_civicrm_post are automatically deleted in Civi 4.6

Tags: api, hooks, developer

I have a custom extension "Automatic Soft Credit", which replicates a function from Raiser's Edge - if contact A has the relationship "Automatically Soft Credits" to contact B, then any contributions for contact A will automatically be soft credited to contact B.

In Civi 4.4, this function worked fine.  In Civi 4.6, the soft credit is successfully created - and then immediately deleted!  The `$result` below returns success, but the soft credit isn't in the database - but the auto-increment happens, so it seems to be created then deleted.

After some experimentation, I found that if I try creating a soft credit to a DIFFERENT contribution, it works.  Confusing!

What could be happening after `hook_civicrm_post` that would cause a soft credit attached to the contribution to be deleted?

```
function automaticsoftcredit_civicrm_post( $op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef ) {
  if($op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Contribution'){
    $cid = $objectRef->contact_id;

    //Look up whether this person has a relationship_type_id that's automatically soft credited
    $params = array(
     'version' => 3,
      'sequential' => 1,
      'contact_id_a' => $cid,
      'relationship_type_id' => 11, //FIXME: This relationship_type_id is currently hardcoded, we should load it from settings
    );
    $result = civicrm_api('Relationship', 'get', $params);
    //if we have the auto soft credit relationship for one or more contacts, create a soft credit for each
    if($result['count'] > 0) {
      unset($params);
      foreach ($result['values'] as $relationship) {
        $params = array(
          'sequential' => 1,
          'contribution_id' => $objectId,
          'contact_id' => $relationship['contact_id_b'],
          'amount' => $objectRef->total_amount,
        );
        $result = civicrm_api3('ContributionSoft', 'create', $params);
CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('result', $result);

      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with code introduced in CRM-16804, and is specific to soft credits.  It's not a generic API issue as I'd feared.  I'll update this answer with a more complete solution once I've nailed it down.